# Overcoming inode limitation

Tags: unix, filesystems, inode

**What's the best practise for storing a large (expanding) number of small files on a server, without running into inode limitations?**

For a project, I am storing a large number of small files on a server with 2TB HD space, but my limitation is the 2560000 allowed inodes. Recently the server used up all the inodes and was unable to write new files. I subsequently moved some files into databases, but others (images and json files remain on the drive). I am currently at 58% inode usage, so a solution is required imminently.

The reason for storing the files individually is to limit the number of database calls. Basically the scripts will check if the file exists and if so, then return results dependently. Performance wise this makes sense for my application, but as stated above it has limitations.

As I understand it does not help to move the files into sub-directories, because each inode points to a file (or a directory file), so in fact I would just use up more inodes.

Alternatively I might be able to bundle the files together in an archive type of file, but that will require some sort of indexing.

Perhaps I am going about this all wrong, so any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could split up your storage area in separate file systems. Should be not too hard with a volume manager.

Comment: Or you use the loop back device to mount some top level folders as separate volumes. That also adds a "virtual layer" and allows you to treat the folders as separate file systems.

Comment: And it is possible to raise the number of inodes available for some file system types. I expect to have to create a new file system for that, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip, it sounds like a good idea. However, I have zero experience with volume management on unix - is it similar to partitioning a HD?
Do you know of a good tutorial to do this? I would hate to bring down the prod server, due to fumble-fingers.

Comment: Partitioning a hard drive is an OS independent thing. That is just a hardware preparing step to be able to use the hardware to create file systems on it afterwards. Even the fil system creation step does not _really_ depend on the OS apart from the fact that you have to start a "program" for that (whatever "starting a program" actually means...). It only gets OS specific when it comes to _using_ file systems or volumes, the so called "mounting" into the local file system hierarchy".

Comment: I am not aware of a "tutorial" about mounting disk volumes on a unixoid system. I'd say that you can pretty much experiment without too much risk, since mounting either fails or succeeds, but that does _not_ affect other parts of the file system at all... But you are certainly right that one should not experiment on a production system. So take any system you have which is not used, install some Linux system on it or some BSD variant, whatever, and give it a try. You can even use a virtual machine for that, though disk management on the host adds complexity in such a situation.

Answer (score 0):

On the advice of [arkascha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1248114/arkascha) I looked into loop devices and found some documentation about [losetup](https://linux.die.net/man/8/losetup). Remains to be tested.